# Add rows based on condition and also create and update new columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with few thousand rows, subset of it is below

```
    fr  var
    1.1 10px
    2.9 12pz
```

Expected Output:

```
    fr  var    vard  varv
    1.1 10px    -5   xval
    1.1 10px     5   zval
    2.9 12pz    -6   zval
    2.9 12pz     6   xval
```

For rows - Each row is to be split into two

Conditions for new columns:

- 'vard' - divide the numeric part of 'var' column by 2 and store it as two rows in 'vard', one negative and one positive value.
- 'varv' - if 'px' is in 'var column' and 'vard' has negative value, then 'varv' should be 'xval' else 'zval'.
- Similarly if 'pz' is in 'var' column and 'vard' has negative value, then 'varv' should be 'zval' else 'xval'.

I have read through various answers with almost similar problems and tried many option like 'iterrows', 'shift', 'explode' etc but not able to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) first for numeric and non numeric part, convert numeric part to integers and divide by `2`, then join with multiple value by `-1` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), sorting index and create default, last use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set new values by conditions:

```
df[['vard','varv']] = df['var'].str.extract('(\d+)(\D+)')
df['vard'] = df['vard'].astype(int).div(2)
df = pd.concat([df, df.assign(vard = df['vard']*-1)]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

m = (df['varv'].eq('px') & df['vard'].lt(0)) | df['varv'].eq('pz') & df['vard'].gt(0)
df['varv'] = np.where(m, 'zval','xval')
print (df)
    fr   var  vard  varv
0  1.1  10px   5.0  xval
1  1.1  10px  -5.0  zval
2  2.9  12pz   6.0  zval
3  2.9  12pz  -6.0  xval
```

Answer (score 0):

it is something that can easily be done using the melt function.

```
# recreate your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fr','var'])
df['fr']=[1.1,2.9]
df['var']=['10px','12pz']

# split the var into its two components by creating two new columns
df['vard_p'] = df['var'].str[:-2]
df['vard_p'] = df['vard_p'].astype(float)/2
df['vard_n'] = -df['vard_p']

# get the vard from the var (I assumed it was simply the last character in the string)
df['varv'] = df['var'].str[-1]+'val'

# and here you melt on the two new vard columns to get the dataframe in the format you wanted
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['fr','var','varv'], value_vars=['vard_p','vard_n'])

# now rename or drop the new columns
df.rename(columns={'value':'vard'},inplace=True)
df.drop('variable',axis=1,inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

```
    fr  var     varv    vard
0   1.1 10px    xval    5.0
1   2.9 12pz    zval    6.0
2   1.1 10px    xval    -5.0
3   2.9 12pz    zval    -6.0
```

Hope it helped